# when constant scalar curvature implies Einstein?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Assume that $(M^n,g)$ is an $n$ dimensional ($n \geq 3$) closed Riemannian manifold with constant scalar curvature and $Ric_g$ nonnegative. Then is $g$ Einstein?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no reason for this, and the answer is indeed **no**.

The simplest example I can think of is the product of two $\mathbb{S}^2$, each endowed with round metrics *of different radius* (added in edit). This manifold is homogeneous and thus has constant scalar curvature, its sectional curvature is non-negative so its Ricci tensor also is (and is in fact even positive), but the Ricci curvature in a direction $u$ is not constant (directions tangent to the largest radius sphere have smallest Ricci curvature).

Comment:  
Yes, I think your example has scalar curvature equal to 4 and Ricci curvature nonnegative. But some sectional curvature is zero. Thank you very much. 

Comment: $S^1\times S^2$ works too. 

Comment: Just a caveat, for this metric on $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2$ not to be Einstein, the two $\mathbb{S}^2$ need to have different radius. And a remark about Agol's comment : what I like in it is that it in fact doesn't admit any Einstein metric, just because in dimension 3 Einstein is equivalent to constant sectional curvature. I wonder wether $\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^3$ enjoys the same property or not...

Comment: This comment comes very late but it is maybe worth to post it: $S^1\times S^3$ does not admit an Einstein metric because the Euler Characteristic is zero. In this case (this is special in dimension $4$), the manifold must be flat, and since it is simply-connected, it must be $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: @KlausKröncke, can you give a bit more details? Why must the manifold be flat? Why can't it have say a non-zero Weyl tensor?

Comment: I think I get it. Is it because the Pfaffian of the curvature must be for a closed oriented Ricci flat $4$-manifold a non-negative function ($|W|^2$) times the volume form? So in this case the curvature must vanish identically, by Gauss-Bonnet?

Comment: @Malkoun: Chern-Gauss-Bonnet gives $$\chi(M) = \frac{1}{32\pi^2}\int_M(|\operatorname{Riem}|^2 - 4|\operatorname{Ric}|^2 + R^2)d\mu = \int_M(|\operatorname{Riem}|^2 - 4|\operatorname{Ric}\limits^{\circ}|^2)d\mu$$ where $\operatorname{Ric}\limits^{\circ}$ denotes the trace-free Ricci curvature. So on an Einstein four-manifold, $\chi(M) = \frac{1}{32\pi^2}\int_M |\operatorname{Riem}|^2d\mu$. In particular, $\chi(M) = 0$ if and only if $M$ is flat.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, yes, thank you. So essentially I was right, up to rearranging curvature terms maybe, and some factor. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese     Does that really mean that M is flat everywhere, or that the AVERAGE Riemann curvature (squared) vanishes?

Comment: @R.Rankin: It means that it is flat. Note that $|\operatorname{Riem}|^2 \geq 0$ so $\int_M|\operatorname{Riem}|^2d\mu = 0$ if and only if $|\operatorname{Riem}|^2 \equiv 0$ and hence $\operatorname{Riem} \equiv 0$.

Answer (score 5):

As an example where this does hold, for $\omega$ a Kähler metric of constant scalar curvature with $\pi c_1(M) = \lambda [\omega]$, then $\omega$ is Kähler-Einstein. This is Proposition 2.12 in Tian's "Canonical metrics in Kähler Geometry".

Comment:  Thank you for telling me this interesting reference.